# Oneliner vanilla CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

During development I often need something like a div showing **LOADING**.

```
<span id=loading style=display:block;font-size:40px;color:red>LOADING</span>
```

Once something has finished loading I will do `style.display='none'`. Now I want to have a simple animation to attract an attention. It could be anything, blinking of text of underline, moving, marquee, appearing dots... whatever. The real requirement is to be vanilla CSS and be really short to type.

All I can find so far takes at least a dozen of lines. I am looking for an oneliner or better a single property of any kind.

I envision it as something like `style=bouncing:fast 2px;` (that's just my IMAGINATION)

Comment: ...why? Why one line? I don't think file size matters these days...

Comment: Just stick your animations to a class and add that, why would you care about external stylesheet length in this context?

Answer (score -1):

A few lines don't really matter. If you're looking to only use Css, I would use CSS3 Animation:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp